# PHP MySQL getting top five highest results.?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

have a poll table which has 10 categories and I want to view the top 5 results from highest to lowest limit into 5 categories. How can I do this in php and mysql?

here are example tables

### categories

- id
- category_name

### Votes

- id
- category_id
- user_id

### Users

- id
- username

here is my sample query:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * from categories");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($q){

  $votes = mysql_query("SELECT * from votes where category_id=".$data['id']."");
  $data_vote = mysql_nuw_rows($votes);
  echo $data['category_name']."has".$data_vote."Votes";
}
```

I want my output to be like this from the highest votes in a categories

```
category1 has 30 votes
category3 has 25 votes
category5 has 23 votes
category2 has 15 votes
category4 has 10 votes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT c.category_name,
                         COALESCE(COUNT(v.category_id), 0) AS cnt
                    FROM CATEGORIES c
               LEFT JOIN VOTES v ON v.category_id = c.id 
                GROUP BY c.category_name
                ORDER BY cnt DESC
                   LIMIT 5 ");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($q) {
  echo $data['category_name'] ." has ". $data['cnt'] ." votes"
}
```

Comment: That's it, critically enough.

Comment: @Ben: Thank you, I really appreciate the feedback & the downvote reversal.

Answer (score 2):

That query should do it:

```
select c.category_name, count(v.id) as number_of_votes 
  from CATEGORIES c
left join VOTES v on v.category_id = c.id
    group by c.id
    order by number_of_votes desc
    limit 5
```

(assuming your VOTES table primary key is "id"

Comment: I corrected a mysql error 1064 - syntax error, because you had the `GROUP BY` after the `ORDER BY`.  Also, the `COUNT(v.id)` will return NULL when a category doesn't have any votes associated to it.

Comment: @OMG. I guess a right join would fix the null value issue then

Comment: No, just need to convert the NULL to zero, using [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) (ANSI) or [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) (native MySQL)